# How to collide the fixtures when askew or slope?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I want to collide vall and block but not able to collide ball and block when I commnet two lines of code but If I uncomment two lines of code the block showing horizontal not askew or like slope.

Please check my coe:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {



        static int padding=20;


        self.touchEnabled = YES;

        // Create block and add it to the layer
        CCSprite *block = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"block.png"];
        int xOffset = padding+block.contentSize.width/2 +  ((block.contentSize.width+padding)*i);
        block.position = ccp(xOffset, 250);
        block.tag = 2;
        [self addChild:block];

        // Create block body
        b2BodyDef blockBodyDef;
        blockBodyDef.type = b2_dynamicBody;   //b2_dynamicBody  ,b2_staticBody
        blockBodyDef.position.Set(xOffset/PTM_RATIO, 250/PTM_RATIO);
        blockBodyDef.userData = block;
        b2Body *blockBody = _world->CreateBody(&blockBodyDef);



        // Create block shape
```

// These two lines creates problem If I unblock two lines the code working fine but All 4 block showing horizontal on only one line but the ball can hit the block. I want ball hit the block and block will show horizontally.

```
     //   b2PolygonShape blockShape;
    //    blockShape.SetAsBox(block.contentSize.width/PTM_RATIO/2,      block.contentSize.height/PTM_RATIO/2);




      //////////////////////////////  If I comment the these lines and uncomment above two line the block will show horizontally and ball can hit the block. But I want this code to show my block slope like. This is must. I want block will show slope and ball can hit the block.

        b2PolygonShape blockShape;
        int num = 3;
        b2Vec2 verts[] = {
            b2Vec2(27.5f / PTM_RATIO, 296.6f / PTM_RATIO),
            b2Vec2(14.3f / PTM_RATIO, 127.2f / PTM_RATIO),
            b2Vec2(187.0f / PTM_RATIO, 288.4f / PTM_RATIO),
            b2Vec2(400.0f / PTM_RATIO, 288.4f / PTM_RATIO)
        };
        blockShape.Set(verts, num);
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////







        // Create shape definition and add to body
        b2FixtureDef blockShapeDef;
        blockShapeDef.shape = &blockShape;
        blockShapeDef.density = 10.0;
        blockShapeDef.friction = 0.0;
        blockShapeDef.restitution = 0.1f;
        blockBodyDef.angle = 45/PTM_RATIO;
         //blockShapeDef.angle = angle * 4.1;
        //blockShapeDef->angle = angle * 0.0174533f;
        //blockBody->SetTransform(b2Vec2(2, 45));
        //blockBodyDef->angle = Math.PI / 180 * 30;//30°
        //float32 angle2 = blockBody->GetAngle();
        blockBody->CreateFixture(&blockShapeDef);









    }
```

Any idea or suggestion would be highly welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your exact issue is, but I did find some problems with your code:

1. You are setting the angle for the body incorrectly.  You need to do it in radians, not degrees.  And you need to set it on the body transform:

   // I don't believe this works...
     //blockBodyDef.angle = CC_DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(45);

   ...

   //float32 angle2 = blockBody->GetAngle();
     blockBody->CreateFixture(&blockShapeDef);
     // My Modified Line
     blockBody->SetTransform(blockBody->GetPosition(), CC_DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(40));
2. I used your SetAsBox(...) method, but accounted for the scale factor of the sprite:

   block.scale = 0.25f;  // I added this for testing

   b2PolygonShape blockShape;
   blockShape.SetAsBox(block.scale*block.contentSize.width/PTM_RATIO/2,
                     block.scale*block.contentSize.height/PTM_RATIO/2);

When I did all this, I got four boxes that started in the middle of the screen (rotated 40 degrees), then fell to ground and rolled flat.  Was this what you were trying to do?